# Joomla! 2.5 Category Article Quick Jump Module

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, ms-query

I have searched on the JDE but i can't find any extension that  can do or that i can modify. I want a module that query  a selected top category then filters the second sub category then displays the articles in the second category as a list in the third input box and on select any of them, it jumps to that articles page. Please see the attached image. So on select the article, it redirects to that articles URL.
[image: See illustration here]

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of as a starting point is going to be an article filter. You can try this one - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/search-a-indexing/site-search/12819